# Kafka messages from topic are being replayed after consumer restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am facing a strange a problem in kafka that all kafka messages from topic are being replayed after consumer application restart. Can anyone help me what am I doing wrong here ?

Here is my configuration:

**spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest**

**spring.kafka.enable.auto.commit= false**

**My Producer configuration:**

```
        producerconfigs.put(ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
        producerconfigs.put(ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        producerconfigs.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "client.id");
        producerconfigs.put(RETRIES_CONFIG, Integer.toString(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        producerconfigs.put(MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 5);
        producerconfigs.put(TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "V1-"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

**Consumer Configuration :**

```
        consumerconfig.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        consumerconfigs.put(SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "10000");
        consumerconfigs.put("isolation.level", "read_committed");
```

**Consumer code :**

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "TOPIC-1", groupId = "TOPIC-GRP", containerFactory = "kaListenerContainerFactory",concurrency = "10", autoStartup = "true")
public String processMesage(@Payload String message,@Header(value = KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, required = false) String correlationId,@Header(value = KafkaHeaders.OFFSET, required = false) String offset) throws JsonProcessingException {//business logic goes here }
```

**Container Code**

```
     @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> 
                kafkaListenerContainerFactory(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new 
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryString());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        return factory;
    }
```

**consumer config**

```
            Map<String, Object> getConsumerProperties() {
         Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
          environment.getProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers"));
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, 
       environment.getProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.group-id"));
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, 
        environment.getProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset"));
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, 
       environment.getProperty("spring.kafka.enable.auto.commit"));
        config.put(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
      environment.getProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer"));
        config.put(VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,  
      environment.getProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer"));
        config.put("isolation.level", "read_committed");
        return config;
    }
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=consumer-group
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.enable.auto.commit= false
```

Comment: You need to show your container factory configuration and/or `application.properties.yml`.

Comment: Please delete this and edit the question instead. Code/config doesn't render well in comments.

Comment: @GaryRussell, As suggested, My question has been edited and added necessary configuration. Please check

Comment: Please read up on Stack Overflow markdown. With that configuration, the offsets for the current poll will be committed just before the next poll (`AckMode.BATCH`). You can see commit activity by changing the containerProperty `commitLogLevel` to, e.g. INFO. `factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(...);`.

Comment: Since your listener method is getting one record at a time, setBatchListener must not be true.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell for your input.                                  Regarding AckMode. Is this configuration correct ?
 `factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);
 factory.getContainerProperties().getCommitLogLevel();`

Comment: BATCH is the default, so it's not needed; but, for that method signature, you also need to change the batch mode flag (which is a totally different thing).

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell   I have couple of questions                               1. when and what time offset will be committed if the 'auto commit is FALSE and  send message Asynchronously and no manual commit in the consumer code' ?            
 2. when and what time offset will be committed if the 'auto commit is FALSE and  send message **synchronously** and no manual commit in the consumer code' ?                                                                         3.  Could you pls elaborate usage of batch mode flag ? If I use it , will performance  degrade ?

Comment: Producers and consumers are independent, it makes no difference how records are published. When a container polls a consumer, it gets a batch of records. With a record listener, the offset is committed either after each record is processed (`AckMode.RECORD`) or all offsets for the batch are committed after the whole batch is processed (`AckMode.BATCH` - default). With a batch listener, the offsets are all committed after the batch is processed. Performance depends on what the listener does with the records. Often, there will be little difference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if someone has answered the question, but it seems config is causing the issue.

Auto commit false mean kafka topic will never have information of offset traversed by consumer group and auto-offset-reset earliest mean always read from beginning.

```
spring.kafka.enable.auto.commit= false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```